# sql query to get today new records compared with yesterday

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this table:

COD (Integer) (PK)
ID (Varchar)
DATE (Date)

I just want to get the new ID's from today, compared with yesterday (the ID's from today that are not present yesterday)

This needs to be done with just one query, maximum efficiency because the table will have 4-5 millions records

As a java developer i am able to do this with 2 queries, but with just one is beyond my knowledge so any help would be so much appreciated

EDIT: date format is dd/mm/yyyy and every day each ID may come 0 or 1 times

Comment: How many records do you get for each ID on each day?

Comment: thanks for the question Gordon, I am going to edit my question to add further info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that will go over the base data one time only. It selects the id and the date where the date is either yesterday or today (or both). Then it GROUPS BY id - each group will have either one or two rows. Then it filters by the condition that the MIN date in the group is "today". Those are the id's that exist today but did not exist yesterday.

DATE is an Oracle keyword, best not used as a column name. I changed that to DT. I also assume that your "dt" field is a pure date (as pure as it can be in Oracle, meaning: time of day, which is always present, is 00:00:00).

```
select   id
from     your_table
where    dt in (trunc(sysdate), trunc(sysdate) - 1)
group by id
having   min(dt) = trunc(sysdate)
;
```

**Edit**:  Gordon makes a good point: perhaps you may have more than one such row per ID, in the same day? In that case the time-of-day may also be different from 00:00:00.

If so, the solution can be adapted:

```
select   id
from     your_table
where    dt >= trunc(sysdate) - 1 and dt < trunc(sysdate) + 1
group by id
having   min(dt) >= trunc(sysdate)
;
```

Either way: (1) the base table is read just once; (2) the column DT is not wrapped within any function, so if there is an index on that column, it can be used to access just the needed rows.

Comment: Good solution.  Remove `, dt` from your select list, though.

Comment: @thorstenkettner - right, thank you for catching it. Fixed now.

Comment: it turns out I need the COD too, how would you change the query to get it??

Comment: @leccionesonline - If you read the answers closely, you will see we allow for the possibility that you may have more than one row per day. If that is NOT the case, and you have only one per day per id at most, then add `max(cod) as cod` to the `select` clause: `select id, max(cod) as cod`. This will work also if there are several rows possible for the same `id` for the same day; in that case only one `cod` will be returned (and your additional request is not well-defined in that case).

Answer (score 1):

The typical method would use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date >= trunc(sysdate) and t.date < trunc(sysdate + 1) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.date >= trunc(sysdate - 1) and t2.date < trunc(sysdate)
                 );
```

This is a general solution.  If you know that there is at most one record per day, there are better solutions, such as using `lag()`.

Comment: yes, there is at most one record per day, how it would be the query with lag() ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `MINUS`. I suppose your date column has a time part, so you need to truncate it.

```
select id from mytable where trunc(date) = trunc(sysdate)
minus
select id from mytable where trunc(date) = trunc(sysdate) - 1;
```

I suggest the following function index. Without it, the query would have to full scan the table, which would probably be quite slow.

```
create idx on mytable( trunc(sysdate) , id );
```

Comment: The proper way to use an index on "date" is to not wrap it within a function call at all. Function calls are expensive (even if there is a function based index), and FBI's are expensive too. In addition, the OP asked specifically for a query that goes over the base table once, not twice.

Comment: @mathguy: The OP asked for a single query rather than to have to run two queries and do the comparision in Java, as far as I understand. The function `trunc(date)` would not get called when running the query, as its result can be read from the index. With an equality comparision, I suppose this to outperform `where date >= trunc(sysdate) and date < trunc(sysdate) 1`, but I may be wrong. Well, in case the time part in `date` is always 00:00:00, there is no issue and we can replace `trunc(date)` by `date` in the query and index. I just thought, I should mention this.